# Performance monitoring for apache websites

Tags: apache-2.2, performance-monitoring

I am after something that will monitor cpu/mem usage for different apache sites. I have a web server that runs multiple websites (on different domains) and wondering if there is a tool (hopefully web-base that can send email alerts) that will show the cpu and memory usage for each website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

apachetop will help you.

[image]
<sub>(source: [googlecode.com](http://apachetop.googlecode.com/files/apachetop.png))</sub>

Comment: where can I download it?

Answer (score 1):

Apache worker processes are generally shared across all the sites on a server - when a request for any of the sites served by Apache comes in, one of the available workers processes it - so there's not really a way to say "this much CPU/RAM was used by site 1".

Answer (score 1):

Munin can do this (web graph and email alerts), but, only on a per server basis, not for individual sites due to the limitations described by ceejayoz.